# mysql restarting

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-error-1045

I cannot get into mysql because I get this message:

```
    ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I can get around that by killing mysql and restarting it with
        --skip-grant-tables

But suddenly I cannot stop mysql.  Every time I kill it, it starts again

```
    betty@bettypc:~$ sudo killall -v mysqld
    [sudo] password for betty: 
    Killed mysqld(4503) with signal 15
    betty@bettypc:~$ ./doMysqld
    Mysql daemon is already running
    betty@bettypc:~$ sudo killall -v mysqld
    Killed mysqld(4965) with signal 15
    betty@bettypc:~$ ps -ef | grep mysql
    mysql     5077     1  2 00:03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
    betty     5175  4900  0 00:03 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
    betty@bettypc:~$ sudo killall -9 mysqld
    mysql     5185     1  4 00:03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
    betty     5283  4900  0 00:03 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

what shall I do?

Comment: **Never** send SIGKILL to mysqld unless you don't care about losing data. Why do you expect to be able to login to root without a password in the first place?

Comment: Try removing the lock if it exists. `rm /var/lock/subsys/mysql`

Comment: Why aren't you stopping mysql with something like `service mysql stop`?

Comment: Thank you Paulo.  I just found service mysql stop yesterday, and it does work.